# Magento : How can merge payment and shipping method steps to checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, payment-methods, shipping-methods

I want display payment method and shipping method on one single step on checkout page.

I have merged billing and shipping address steps in single step.

Comment: Are you talking about the Onepage Checkout? The Magento default configuration is in `System > Configuration > Checkout` and then `Enable Onepage Checkout`, but if you are using a custom theme, your theme settings probably has this option already.

Comment: I am taking about normal steps checkout but I want to merge steps of shipping and payment method.

Answer (score 0):

There are several extensions out there that merge all checkout steps into a single interface instead of the default accordion style onepage checkout magento offers. Browse connect to find one that fits you needs more closely.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/express-checkout-one-step-checkout.html

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/one-step-checkout-v4-5.html

Comment: I already know about one step check out extension but I have total 4 step checkout that's why I want to merge only shipping and payment method in one step.